# How can i update the results of a MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SELECT query...

```
SELECT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.email,
users.live, users.editoverride, 
usertenderstage.tenderId, 
usertenderstage.stageId, usertenderstage.statusId
FROM users
JOIN usertenderstage ON usertenderstage.userId = users.id
WHERE users.live = 1 AND usertenderstage.tenderId = 1 
AND usertenderstage.stageId = 2 AND usertenderstage.statusid = 6
```

I am trying to edit the query to make it an UPDATE query, and set users.editoverride = 1. My attempt is below...

```
UPDATE users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.email,
users.live, users.editoverride, 
usertenderstage.tenderId, 
usertenderstage.stageId, usertenderstage.statusId
FROM users
JOIN usertenderstage ON usertenderstage.userId = users.id
SET users.editOverride = 1
WHERE users.live = 1 AND usertenderstage.tenderId = 1 
AND usertenderstage.stageId = 2 AND usertenderstage.statusid = 6
```

But I am getting error message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'FROM users
JOIN usertenderstage ON usertenderstage.userId = users.id
SET users' at line 5
```

Could someone please help me to know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: show your current efforts

Comment: this is a select query. you need to write a new one that is an update query

Comment: I strongly recommend you read [how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create Minimal, Complete and Verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then quickly edit your question accordingly before it get downvoted and burried.

Comment: We won't be able to help you if you even don't provide the error message. Furthermore, you probably should show the table creation statements so that we can see indexes and data types, and provide the sample data your query operates on. There are many experts around here, but no prophets (as far as I know).

Comment: What does "I'm not doing it right" mean?

Comment: I have edited the question. You know, you guys are really not very nice to people trying to learn the best way to use the site.

Comment: @LeeColarelli We are trying to help you.  In return, we expect you to provide the necessary information.  First of all, show your attempt, even if it doesn't work.  Second, tell why it doesn't work.  Eg: wrong result.  Provide sample input and output of the right result.  Just think how "I'm not doing it right" will help us help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

```
UPDATE users
SET editoverride = 1
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT users.id
     FROM users
     JOIN contractorscontractsappliedfor ON contractorscontractsappliedfor.contractorId = users.id
     JOIN usertenderstage ON usertenderstage.userId = users.id
     WHERE users.live = 1
       AND contractorscontractsappliedfor.contractid = 1
       AND usertenderstage.stageId = 2
       AND usertenderstage.statusid = 6)
```

It seems the issue is with MySQL as you are getting error "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause". To get around, nest it one level deep as below:

```
UPDATE users
SET editoverride = 1
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT A.id
     FROM
       (SELECT users.id
        FROM users
        JOIN contractorscontractsappliedfor ON contractorscontractsappliedfor.contractorId = users.id
        JOIN usertenderstage ON usertenderstage.userId = users.id
        WHERE users.live = 1
          AND contractorscontractsappliedfor.contractid = 1
          AND usertenderstage.stageId = 2
          AND usertenderstage.statusid = 6) AS A)
```

I haven't tested it as don't have MySQL handy.

Comment: Thanks Pranav. I realised I don't need the contractid, so I've edited it slightly as follows:-

`UPDATE users
    SET editoverride = 1
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT users.id
     FROM users
     JOIN usertenderstage ON usertenderstage.userId = users.id
     WHERE users.live = 1
       AND usertenderstage.tenderId = 1
       AND usertenderstage.stageId = 2
       AND usertenderstage.statusid = 6)`

but i am getting error message "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Thanks for your help!